# Is it possible to customise a Floating Filter to handle Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, filter, wildcard, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I would like to be able to use the free text input of the Floating Filter as a regular expression parser. Meaning that, for example, if in my Floating Filter I Have a value "Greg*", the filtered data should contain all values starting with "Greg".

[Expected Usage Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIZ33.png)

I want to be able to implement my own regular expressions rules to it. I understand I can do it in the filter button on the right but I want to do it on the free text input visible, without having the user clicking on a button.

Comment: May someone point me out to any issue on this question? Thanks!

Comment: Why was this question voted down ?  This is a really good question, I also want to know the answer to it, and, as usual, agGrid's own examples completely avoid mentioning this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my question after looking more closely to the ag-grid documentation, thing that I should have done from the start

Since Floating Filters are actually showing their parent Filter state, one should then implement his own custom Filter and Floating Filter together. So I implemented two classes **CustomTextFilter** and **CustomTextFloatingFilter**, implementing respectively **IFilterComp** and **IFloatingFilterComp** from the ag-grid library.

```
export class CustomTextFilter implements IFilterComp{
    // IFilterComp method implementations here [...]
}

export class CustomTextFloatingFilter implements IFilterComp{
    // IFilterComp method implementations here [...]
}
```

Within **CustomTextFilter** class, the most important is to implement the ***doesFilterPass*** method, where we can implement our regexp logic. Below is an example with a rule that allows us to search for multiple strings separated by a comma:

```
doesFilterPass(params: IDoesFilterPassParams): boolean {
    var passed = false;
    var valueGetter = this.valueGetter;
    var filterText = this.eFilterText.value

    if (this.isFilterActive()) {
        var value = valueGetter(params);
        passed = filterText.toLowerCase().split(",").some((word: any) => {
            return word !== null && word !== undefined && word.trim() !== '' 
                && value.toString().toLowerCase().trim().indexOf(word) >= 0;
        });
    }  
    return passed;
}
```

Then in **CustomFloatingFilter** we make sure that we that we listen to the input event so we can transfer the value from the floating filter to the parent filter, and then refresh the grid:

```
init(params: IFloatingFilterParams): void {
    // Some gui code here [...]

    this.eFilterInput = this.gui.querySelector('input');
    this.eFilterText = this.gui.querySelector('#floatingFilterText');

    var that = this;
    this.eFilterText.addEventListener("input", (event: any) => {
        that.filterText = event.target.value;
        params.parentFilterInstance((instance: any) => {
            instance.setModel({ value: that.filterText });
            instance.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
        });
    });
}
```

Hope this will help!